# Creating a Virtual Host on a local development machine

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I'm having issues with creating a Virtual Host on my Ubuntu Apache2 setup for local development.

I'm better familiar with httpd.conf running CentOS 6.5 and don't seem to be able to figure out how to set this up on newer version of apache.

So I created a config file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and enabled it with `a2ensite`

The file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName fih.localhost
    ServerAlias www.fih.localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fih/
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have than restarted the the apache2 service but when I try entering fih.localhost I get `server not found`. I know that the DocumentRoot is fine because localhost/fih works fine.

I have been trying to look this up for days and I have not been able to find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does the fih.localhost already resolve to an ip-address?

You can test this by typing the following in a command-prompt :

```
ping fih.localhost
```

It should resolve to an IP. If it does not do that, you will probably want to fix that by putting that servername in your computer's `/etc/hosts`-file.